# Why does function passed as an argument in post method does not return the value?

Tags: javascript, function, post

I am trying to learn JavaScript and following a Udemy course along. In that the simple app i am working on is a to-do app which connects to a MongoDb database in the backend. At this point what should happen is once the user added a to do item to the field, it should goes to the database and the user should be presented with a text called Hello that is done on a different page called /create-item. I use the following function for the said purpose.

```
server.post("/create-item", function (req, res) {
db.collection("to-do-items").insertOne({ to_do: req.body.item }, function () {
res.send(`<h1>Hello That is done</h1>`);
});
```

The problem is the data gets added to the database with no issue.But the user is not being presented with 'Hello That is done' text.

Also, if i update the code as follows it just takes me to /create-item page but obviously it wont post the data to the database.

```
server.post("/create-item", function (req, res) {
//db.collection("to-do-items").insertOne({ to_do: req.body.item }, function () {
res.send(`<h1>Hello That is done</h1>`);
});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a handler to see if there aren't any errors

```
server.post("/create-item", function (req, res) {
  db.collection("to-do-items").insertOne({ to_do: req.body.item }, function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return res.send(error);
    }

    res.send(`<h1>Hello That is done</h1>`);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the lead. I replaced the post function with the above but when I ran the application there was no error on the console as well. This is very weird.

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost two days trying to find a fix. I attempted various MongoDb versions, same post method but with error catching mechanisms. However, it finally boiled down to the following code.

```
server.post("/create-item", function (req, res) {
db.collection("items").insertOne({ to_do: req.body.item }, function () {
 res.redirect("http://localhost:2227");
});
});
```

The only change in above is, instead of redirecting to ('/') I have defined it as ('http://localhost:2227'). Not sure what went wrong but that fixed my issue.

Comment: I think I was wrong with my above answer. Well the root cause was the version of MongoDB driver in place. It was originally at version 5 but I had to downgrade it to 4.4 using 

npm install mongodb@4.4

and that works flawlessly.